# Is there a way to provide ENV variable to ECS without using task Definition

Tags: terraform, amazon-ecs

I need a way to provide ENV variables to ECS without using task definition. Is there a way to provide ENV vars commonly in the AWS Cluster to use inside ECS? Or is there an any way to provide ENV vars without altering task or container definitions?

Answer (score 2):

If you are running the task via the `RunTask` API, or through another service like EventBridge or StepFunctions that ultimately calls the `RunTask` API, then you can provide [task overrides](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_TaskOverride.html) that can include environment variables.

If you are running your tasks via an ECS Service, then that is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you aware to pass sensitive data to environment variables to container definition, you can use secrets in container definition (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/secrets-envvar.html)

Using SecretsManager:

```
container_definitions = jsonencode([
    {
      name  = "example-container",
      image = "your-container-image",
      secrets = [
        {
          name      = "MYSQL_PASSWORD",
          valueFrom = "${aws_secretsmanager_secret.secrets.arn}:MYSQL_PASSWORD::"
        }
      ]
    }
  ])
```

where `MYSQL_PASSWORD` is a JSON key in the secret value.

2. Workaroud solution. You can create SSM parameter or SecretsManager secret and try to get the value in `docker-entrypoint.sh` of a container like this:

```bash
# ...
$SECRET_VALUE=$(aws ssm get-parameter --name "$SSM_PARAMETER" --with-decryption --query 'Parameter.Value' --output text)
export SECRET_VALUE=$SECRET_VALUE
# ...
```